# Making voltage arrows appear on beamer - Circuitikz

Tags: beamer, circuitikz

I'm trying to make the voltage arrows apear on second frame. Right now i got this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{float}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}



\newcommand{\subb}[1]{_{\mathrm{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\Re}{\mathrm{Re}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw
            (0,0) to[battery,l_=$V\subb{in}$] ++(0,-4) coordinate (v);
            (0,0) to[short]++(1,0)
            \only<1>{
                \draw
                (0,0) to[inductor, l^=$L$,-*] ++(3,0) coordinate (s1);
            }
            \only<2->{
                \draw
                (0,0) to[inductor, l^=$L$,-*,v_=$v\subb L$,i=$i\subb L$] ++(3,0) coordinate (s1);
            }           
            \draw
            ([xshift=15pt, yshift=-15pt]s1) coordinate (son) 
            (son) to[short,o-] (son|-v)
            to[short] (v)
            ([xshift=22pt]s1) coordinate (soff)
            (soff) to[short,o-*]++(2,0) coordinate (c);
            \only<1>{
                \draw
                (c) to[C,l_=$C$]  (c|-v) coordinate (cc);
            }
            \only<2->{
                \draw
                (c) to[C,l_=$C$,i>_=$i\subb C$]  (c|-v) coordinate (cc);
            }
            \draw
            (cc) to[short,*-*] (cc-|son)
            (c) to[short] ++ (2,0) coordinate (l);

            \only<1>{
                \draw
                (l) to[R,l_=$R\subb L$] (l|-cc) coordinate (pe);
            }
            \only<2->{
                \draw
                (l) to[R,l_=$R\subb L$,v^=$V\subb{out}$,i>_=$i\subb{out}$] (l|-cc) coordinate (pe);
            }
            \draw
            (pe) to[short] (cc);
            \draw [very thick] (s1)--++(19pt,-8pt);
            \node[anchor = north east] at (son) {$T\subb{ON}$};
            \node[anchor = south] at (soff) {$T\subb{OFF}$};
        \end{circuitikz}
        \caption{Boost converter}
        \label{circ:boost_diagrama}
    \end{figure}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

but between frames all the elements in the circuit sifht left to make room for the voltage arrow in the load.
Is there any way to remove that shiffting?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to enlarge the bounding box of the picture. For instance, simply add:

```
\useasboundingbox (l) -- ++(1.5,0);
```

at **the end** of the circuitikz environment. See the `pgf` documentation (section 15.8) for more details.